# Javascript function class object returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback, undefined

Hi Guys I have function and it's returning a javascript class but at runtime returning value is undefined. When I set return value to some global variable and it's gave me right result on Chrome developer console. Why is that happening?

[image]

```
var globalData;

$(document).ready(function(){

var request = postRequest("contact", dt, elem);

        globalData = request;

        console.log(request.status); //this gaves me undefined

});


function returnObj(status, message, projects) {
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
    this.projects = projects;
}



function postRequest(method, vars, elem) {

    var result = new returnObj();

    $.post('api.aspx',
        {
            method: "test"
        },
        function (data, status) {
            var resultObject = $.parseJSON(data);

            result.status = resultObject.status;
            result.message = resultObject.message;
            result.projects = resultObject.projects;


        });

    return result;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: The post is async, when function return "result" the post surely is not yet finish !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `post` ajax request accepts as a third parameter a `callback` function which is asyncronous.

`return result;` statement will be called before the `callback` is finished and that's the reason you're receiving `undefined`.

I recommend you to create a `callback` function.

```
function postRequest(method, vars, elem,callback) {
                                        ^^^^^^^^
     var result = new returnObj();
     $.post('api.aspx',
      {
        method: "test"
      },
      function (data, status) {
          var resultObject = $.parseJSON(data);
          result.status = resultObject.status;
          result.message = resultObject.message;
          result.projects = resultObject.projects;
          callback(result);
     });
}
```

**How to call function:**

```
postRequest(method, vars, elem, function(result) { 
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Why some people downvotes the correct answer ??

Comment: Not my downvote, but you can't return a value from the callback.

Comment: @JJJ, yes,sorry, my mistake.

Comment: thanks you so much. it works